# querying google spreadsheet rows

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Im using the c# google spreadsheets api to work with our spreadsheets.

Im having a problem querying the sheets we have.

Namely Im having a problem trying to get specific rows based on their title,which is the value in the first cell of the row, we are currently not using headers in our spreadheets as we need a vertical layout rather a horizontal one.

```
listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "Select A";
```

from reading the api docs that should be all i need to do there but it throws an error,which is a bad request with null response message..

```
AtomLink ListFeedLink = worksheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel,         null);

ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(ListFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spreadsheetQuery))
{
   listQuery.SpreadsheetQuery = "age=25";
}

ListFeed listFeed = myService.Query(listQuery);
```

Im using the above code

anyone have any tips for querying spreadsheets in this way?

Answer (score 2):

You say: "we are currently not using headers in our spreadsheets". When I tested ListFeed, it needed headers, this was not an optional extra. CellFeed does not require headers and has a search style query, see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/browse/trunk/java/sample/spreadsheet/cell/CellDemo.java

Comment: This is the right answer and should be marked.  You cannot query google spreadsheets by list unless a header row is present.